# Find local minimum in a vector with r

Tags: r, optimization, vector, kernel

Taking the ideas from the following links:

1. [the local minimum between the two peaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264461/find-local-minimum-in-bimodal-distribution-with-r)
2. [How to explain ...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57993/how-to-explain-how-i-divided-a-bimodal-distribution-based-on-kernel-density-esti)

I look for the local minimum or minimums, avoiding the use of functions already created for this purpose [max / min locale or global].
Our progress:

```
#DATA
simulate <- function(lambda=0.3, mu=c(0, 4), sd=c(1, 1), n.obs=10^5) {
  x1 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[1], sd[1])
  x2 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[2], sd[2])    
  return(ifelse(runif(n.obs) < lambda, x1, x2))
}

data <- simulate()
hist(data)
d <- density(data)
#
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/25276661/8409550
##Since the x-values are equally spaced, we can estimate dy using diff(d$y)
d$x[which.min(abs(diff(d$y)))] 
#With our data we did not obtain the expected value
#
d$x[which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))>0)+1]#pit

d$x[which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))<0)+1]#peak
 
#we check
#1
optimize(approxfun(d$x,d$y),interval=c(0,4))$minimum 
optimize(approxfun(d$x,d$y),interval=c(0,4),maximum = TRUE)$maximum 
#2
tp <- pastecs::turnpoints(d$y)
summary(tp)
ind <- (1:length(d$y))[extract(tp, no.tp = FALSE, peak = TRUE, pit = TRUE)]
d$x[ind[2]]
d$x[ind[1]]
d$x[ind[3]]
```

My questions and request for help:

1. Why did the command lines fail:
   `d$x[which.min(abs(diff(d$y)))]`
2. It is possible to eliminate the need to add one to the index in the command lines:

   ```
   d$x[which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))>0)+1]#pit
   d$x[which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))<0)+1]#peak
   ```
3. How to get the optimize function to return the two expected maximum values?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

The answer to the first question is straighforward. The line `d$x[which.min(abs(diff(d$y)))]` asks for the x value at which there was the smallest change in y between two consecutive points. The answer is that this happened at the extreme right of the plot where the density curve is essentially flat:

```
which.min(abs(diff(d$y)))
#> [1] 511

length(abs(diff(d$y)))
#> [1] 511
```

This is not only smaller than the difference at your local maxima /minima points; it is *orders of magnitude* smaller. Let's zoom in to the peak value of `d$y`, including only the peak and the point on each side:

```
which.max(d$y)
#> [1] 324

plot(d$x[323:325], d$y[323:325])
```

[image]

We can see that the smallest difference is around 0.00005, or 5^-5, between two consecutive points. Now look at the end of the plot where it is flattest:

```r
 plot(d$x[510:512], d$y[510:512])
```

[image]

The difference is about 1^-7, which is why this is the flattest point.

---

---

**Question 2**

The answer to your second question is "no, not really". You are taking a double `diff`, which is two elements shorter than x, and if x is `n` elements long, a double diff will correspond to elements 2 to (n - 1) in x. You can remove the `+1` from the index, but you will have an off-by-one error if you do that. If you really wanted to, you could concatenate dummy zeros at each stage of the `diff`, like this:

```r
d$x[which(c(0, diff(sign(diff(c(d$y, 0))))) > 0)]
```

which gives the same result, but this is longer, harder to read and harder to justify, so why would you?

---

---

**Question 3**

The answer to the third question is that you could use the "pit" as the dividing point between the minimum and maximum value of `d$x` to find the two "peaks". If you really want a single call to get both at once, you could do it inside an `sapply`:

```r
pit <- optimize(approxfun(d$x,d$y),interval=c(0,4))$minimum 

peaks <- sapply(1:2, function(i) {
                       optimize(approxfun(d$x, d$y),
                                interval = c(min(d$x), pit, max(d$x))[i:(i + 1)],
                                maximum = TRUE)$maximum
         })

pit
#> [1] 1.691798

peaks
#> [1] -0.02249845  3.99552521
```